# Full news story in email

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-email, sharepoint-news

I understand this isn't an ideal situation - however we need full news stories to be emailed rather than a link and preview. Is this possible, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using SharePoint Online. In SharePoint, the news is in fact a site page with pre-set layout. Per my knowledge we do not have a way to get the content out of the page and send it through an Email.